# Django: NameError at /accounts/register/ name 'Honeyword' is not defined

Tags: python, django, object, hash, passwords

How to import my new custom password hasher ?
It just gives me this error :

```
NameError at /accounts/register/

name 'Honeyword' is not defined
```

hashers.py :

```
class MyHoneywordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "honeyword_base9_tweak3_pbkdf2_sha256"
    iterations = 36000
    digest = hashlib.sha256

    def salt(self):
        salt = get_random_string()
        while Honeyword.objects.filter(salt=salt).exists():
            salt = get_random_string()
        return salt
```

-----**EDITED**-----
import for hashers.py :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64
import binascii
import hashlib
import importlib
import passlib
import hashlib
from collections import OrderedDict 

from django.conf import settings 
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.signals import setting_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import BasePasswordHasher, PBKDF2PasswordHasher
from django.utils.crypto import (
    constant_time_compare, get_random_string, pbkdf2, )

from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string 
from django.utils.translation import gettext_noop as _
```

i just add the import based on the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/ . kinda confused on how to import the my new hasher.

i already create the app(honeywordHasher) and install it in INSTALLED_APP and also in the PASSWORD_HASHERS in settings.py

Comment: Could you post the import statement as well.

Comment: done posting it @RajKris

Comment: I could not see you importing Honeyword anywhere? And that is causing the error.

Comment: i already did it before  this and i give me "cannot be imported" error @RajKris

Comment: Could you post me a link or anything to know about the HoneyWord? Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do here?

Comment: i try to recreate :https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/honeywords/  for my thesis and https://github.com/haiweiosu/HoneyWord/blob/master/case3/myHoneyWord.py for honeyword generator . i try to edit the hashers.py according to https://www.rsaconference.com/writable/presentations/file_upload/dsp-w02-honeywords-a-new-tool-for-protection-from-password-database-breach_final.pdf @RajKris

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157240/discussion-between-rajkris-and-nuradilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change HoneyWords to SweetWords and do the import as follows:

```
from myhoneywordapplication.models import SweetWords
```